# Node.js Restfull API using SQLlite not working with Angular 2 HTTP post

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sqlite

The HTTP POST getting no response. I see no response in the developer tool. What is wrong in the code. Please help. How to get the response from API and add the new record to the list.

**strong text**
//MY REST API CODE:
// Put these statements before you define any routes.

```
var express = require('express');
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('app_data/SocBillSys.db');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app=express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

// This allows any domain access API server.

```
 function allowCrossDomain(req, res, next){
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, 
     PUT, PATCH, DELETE'); // If needed
       res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-       With,contenttype'); // If needed
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true); // If needed
      next();
}
```

// INSERT RECORD

```
app.post('/db/society', function(req,res)
{   

     db.run("INSERT INTO society (name, type, address, city, state, pincode ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)", 
      [ req.body.name,
        req.body.type,
        req.body.address,
        req.body.city,
        req.body.state,
        req.body.pincode ] 
    , 
   function(error,response)
    {
       if (error == null)
          res.status(202).json({"id": this.lastID});

       else 
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
    });

});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('NODE.JS WEB API SERVER is listening at port 3000...');
});
```

ANGULAR SERVICE HTTP CALL

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { ISociety } from '../Society/Society';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class SocietyService {

    constructor(private _http: Http){}

 createSociety(society: ISociety): void{
         let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
         let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});   
         this._http.post('http://localhost:3000/db/society', JSON.stringify(society), options)
            .map(this.handleResponse)
            .catch(this.handleError);         
    }



 private handleResponse(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();       
        return body;
        }

    private handleError (error: Response | any) {
        console.error(error.message || error);
        return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
        }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function allowCrossDomain(req, res, next){
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, 
 PUT, PATCH, DELETE'); // If needed
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type'); // If needed
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true); // If needed
  next();
```

}

Comment: I don't see any difference between your code and my code other than 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type' but that is not an issue. It was just my copy -paste issue.

Comment: Thanks Ayush for your solution. I first could not understand what exactly you corrected but later i got it. I appreciate your help